# Geometry Nodes: Is it possible for bunches of points to get the Z-positions of single points?

Tags: geometry-nodes

So, is this possible without making a 'Set Position' node for all of the corners separately?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a setup that does this, maintaining the original Z position of the points:

[image]

Add a resample like in your (OP, Manu Järvinen) answer if the input can be a Bezier or Nurbs (or anything else than the poly curve).

Comment: Excellent answer!  I could add my Curve Parameter's Factor to the mix and it performed beautifully! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from a friend!

[image]

Comment: Your "Resample Curve: Evaluated" is a no-op (you can alt-drag it away - remove it - without changing the result). However instead of removing this one node, you can remove two nodes converting to mesh and back (then resampling will be useful for bezier or nurbs inputs). The Map Range also does nothing with these settings. The "Named Attribute" is used once and is so close to the "Store Named Attribute", that it asks for those 2 nodes to be replaced with a single "Capture Attribute". The setup changes the heights of original (groups of) points, maybe you want to capture $z$ coordinate instead?